# Browser Remember password set username to other textboxes also

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use browser remembered password, after login, some textboxes in my forms shows username.
I am confused, how it works?
Please provide solution to avoid this problem?

Comment: You can use `AutoComplete=Off` on that controls. There is intelligence in the browser that if there is some password type texbox is there it automatically fills the use name in the textbox just before that.

Comment: There is no password type textbox in form. I have also tried AutoComplete="off", but still it's showing username.

Comment: Provide more detail about the browser which you are using.

Comment: I have used password type textbox in master page because of this last textbox of each form shows the username.

Comment: AutoComplete=Off is not working in my case.
Any other solution?

Comment: There is a trick which may work try to put a texbox before your password textbox and make it's  `display=none` so that it is not visible to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Set `TextBox` property `TextMode` as `Password`

or try this

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");

<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></form>
```

Using `Javascript` you can also delete `history` of textbox

```
function disableautocompletion(id){ 
    var passwordControl = document.getElementById(id);
    passwordControl.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
}
```

Try:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" />
```

this renders as:

```
 <input id="MyTextBox" name="MyTextBox" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

for more info [MSDN for autocomplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032(v=vs.85).aspx)

And this is helpful [link](http://www.dotnetspark.com/links/52333-clear-history-textbox.aspx)

Comment: I Edit my answer ..check it